# Phone Gap: Disable text selection in a webview

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am working on a Phone Gap Project.I am using HTML,JAVA SCRIPT and CSS.

I have implemented onclick ,mapping and ahref functionality in my project.While using this functionality either for onclick or mapping or ahref --while selecting the image or text it gets highlighted.

I don't want it get highlighted.I tried implementing this following code

```
noSelect 
{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

But,this code made no difference in the SELECTING VIEW.

So,please suggest me a way to handle this and solve my problem.

**EDIT:**

This is how i have used it in mapping and image but it isn't working.

**mapping**

```
<div id="main" class="main" ><img src="img/abc.png" alt="abc" usemap="#abc" class="noSelectInputBox:focus"/></div>
```

**image source**

```
document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML = '<img src="img/image1.png" onclick="detail()" class="noSelectInputBox:focus"/> '
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following css to yours:

```
noSelectInputBox:focus
{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    outline:none;
    -webkit-focus-ring-color:rgba(0 0 0 0);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: the class in your HTML needs to be only noSelectInputBox

Comment: SHANK,you mean to say i an call only one class??

Comment: In your HTML code, replace noSelectInputBox:focus by noSelectInputBox

Answer (score 0):

Writing the following code in your css file. While using this we can disable highlighting the contents on touch.

```
*{
    /* Prevent any object from being highlighted upon touch event*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```